# Order Properties on Open Sets

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

Considering the subset order on the open sets of a topological space, it seems natural to ask what kind of total orders exist as suborders of the subset order. One possibility is that each total order is a well order. Where can I read more about this kind of thing?

Comment: I think a search with terms "order topology" will give you relevant results.

Comment: Perhaps you'll want to investigate the subject (aptly?) named [pointless topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointless_topology).

Comment: @Pedro: Searching on *order topology* will primarily give you information on spaces $\langle X,\le,\tau\rangle$ such that $\le$ is a linear order on $X$, and $\tau$ is the order topology generated by that order; this is not what the OP is interested in. The OP is interested in what linear orders can be embedded in the partial order $\langle\tau,\subseteq\rangle$ determined by a space $\langle X,\tau\rangle$, i.e., in the lattice of open sets of some space.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Right, but I thought that using this concept one may prove that any linear order can be embedded in the  poset of open sets, but I didn't check this. If true, this is relevant for the OP, isn't it?

Comment: @Pedro: Yes, and it is true, since $\{(\leftarrow,x):x\in X\}$ will be a chain in the topology order-isomorphic to the order on the LOTS $X$. I didn’t realize that that was what you had in mind: it looked more like you’d misinterpreted the question.

Answer (score 0):

In point set topology, one can define the open sets $\mathcal{T}$ of a topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$ however one wants as long as the elements of $\mathcal{T}$ have the following three properties:  First, both $\varnothing$ and $X$ must be open. Second, the intersection of two open sets must also be open.  Third, the union of any collection of open sets is open.

One can translate these conditions to the language of ordered sets.  Clearly, the subset order on the open sets of a topological has a maximal, has a minimum, has finite infimums, and has arbitrary supremums.  In other words, such an ordered set is a bounded lattice that happens to be closed under arbititrary supremums / 'meets'.

Conversely any lattice $L$ of this sort is actually the set of open sets of a topological space $(L, \mathcal{L})$ as follows:  consider all subsets $\mathcal{L}$ of $L$ that consist of some element $l \in L$ along with all elements $k \in L$ such $k \leq l$.  This class of sets is closed under arbitrary intersection, arbitrary union, and contains both $\varnothing$ and $L$ and thus forms the desired topology.

Going back to your question about *total* suborders of the open set order: any *any* total order $T = (|T|, \leq_T)$ is  a suborder of another total order with both a 'bottom' element (like $\varnothing$) and a 'top' element (like $K$).  This order is, in turn, a supremum closed lattice which is isomorphic to some 'open sets in a topology' order by the paragraph above.

A related question might be which (total?) orders show up in the open subset order of a metric space.  Or, for that matter, any restricted class of topological spaces.  I believe one can say this:  A total order is not the suborder of an open-set order unless it countable.

Comment: Your $\mathcal{L}$ is not closed under unions, and it is not true that every complete lattice is the lattice of open subsets of a space.  There is no particularly simple description of such lattices, but they can be characterized as those complete lattices for which finite meets distribute over arbitrary joins and principal prime ideals separate points.

Comment: I don't get your last sentence. Take the real line, and the following family of open intervals $\{(0,b) : b>0\}$. With $\subseteq$, that's an uncountable total suborder of the (metric) space $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes, I should be more careful.  I'll delete that last line.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is partially based on two comments to the question, one by @BrianM.Scott and one mine. It consists of two observations.

> **Proposition 1.** Every total order $(X,\leq)$ embeds into a $(\mathcal{T},\subseteq)$ for some topology $\mathcal{T}$.

This can be seen by taking $\mathcal{T}$ to be the topology on $X$ with base
$$
\{I(a,b) : a< b \},
$$
where $a,b\in X$ and $I(a,b) := \{x \in X : a<x<b\}$ is the *open interval* with endpoints $a$ and $b$. This construction, called the [order topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology) on $X$, is totally analogous to that of the topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Now it is easy to see that the map 
$$
x\mapsto \{y \in X : y< x\}
$$
is an order embedding.

> **Proposition 2.** Let $(X,\mathcal{T})$ be a $T_1$ topological space. If every total suborder of $(\mathcal{T},\subseteq)$ is a wellorder, then $X$ is finite.

Here, $T_1$ means that singletons are closed (this happens in every Hausdorff space, for example). To prove the Proposition, we show the contrapositive. If $X$ is infinite, take some infinite sequence $\{x_n: n\in \mathbb{N}\}\subseteq X$ and consider the open sets
$$
X \supset X\setminus\{x_1\} \supset X\setminus\{x_1,x_2\}\supset \dots
$$
This is a strictly decreasing $\subseteq$-sequence, hence not a wellorder.